# Finding the volume of a mass with circular base and square slides

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

> The base is a disk of radius $a$. Slices perpendicular to the base are
>   squares.

If we position the center of the disk to the origin, we have the equation $x^2+y^2=a^2$. But we need to integrate using square slices.

Since there is symmetry, we can integrate the part where $y\ge0$ and double:
$$2\int_0^a\left(\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\right)^2\;dx=2\left.\left(a^2x-\frac{x^3}3\right)\right|_0^a=\frac{4a^3}3$$

However, the key at the back of the book says:
$$\int_{-a}^a\left(2\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\right)^2\;dx=\frac{16a^3}3$$

Why does it put that $2$ inside the square? The equation is really $y=\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$ for $y\ge0$ and $y=-\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$ for $y<0$.

Comment: You mean, you are integrating where $x \geq 0$? Anyway, the side of the square is $2y$, not $y$. That's where that $2$ is coming from.

Comment: @mechanodroid Now I see. Thank you. I confused $x$ and $y$, and the way I integrated was wrong: the slices were rectangles (half squares). The $2$ must be inside the square.